# Is there really no music apps for linux that work with the Beatstep Pro

Tags: music

I've got the Arturia Beatstep Pro which I've used with hardware and loved.  I'd like to use it to control my laptop whichis running Ubuntu but I can't find anything compatible.  Am I lookin gin the wrong places or is this real life?!?!?

Comment: How about https://forum.arturia.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=492c9jit0tma3j9g2eqicpvm73&topic=93137.msg158153#msg158153 ? Their forums seem to be the place to ask ;-)

Comment: You can use it as a generic midi controller, but that's about it. The Arturia MIDI Control Center doesn't run on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Pure Data](https://puredata.info/)? I've spent the last two days mapping a BeatStep and a 2-octave keyboard to control 8 sequencers. Without Arturia's software there's only one channel and limited functionality, but the Midi clock and 16 pads can go a long way.

[image: Midi keyboard mapping]